# Display node local tasks on custom page

Tags: 8

I've created a custom route for each nodes, let's say /custom-page/{node}, which renders some specific stuff from a Controller.
On this custom page, I'd like to automatically display the same local tasks as displayed on nodes canonical pages (In my case : View, Edit, Delete, Devel)

I know I can set dynamic local tasks using a Deriver in links.task.yml but how can I load local tasks from another route ?
Or maybe there is a way to tell Drupal to display local tasks as if it was for the route "entity.node.canonical" ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually this was a stupid question...
I was trying to add the node tabs on my custom page without adding a tab to this custom page on the node view itself (entity.node.canonical)
Simply adding the new local task on the node view automatically displays other tabs when viewing any of the tabs

my_module.links.task.yml :

```yaml
my_module.my_custom_tab:
  route_name: my_module.custom_page
  title: 'Custom'
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

Answer (score 1):

CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME.links.task.yml

```
CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME.tab_view:
  title: 'TAB NAME'
  route_name: CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME.CUSTOM_PAGE
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  weight: 5
```

CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME.routing.yml

```
CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME.CUSTOM_PAGE:
  path: 'node/{node}/abc'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\MODULE_NAME\Controller\CONTROLLER_NAME::ACTION_NAME'
    _title: 'TITLE'
  options:
    parameters:
      nodeId:
        entity_type: node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```